# Backplane of a switch

Tags: switch

How to practically find the back plane capacity of any  Ethernet switch ? Also how to calculate the maximum TX and Rx load on trunk port of switch . And calculation of memory and processor utilization at peak time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because really, read the specs for the device in question. Somebody went to the trouble of working it out and documenting it for you.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part: Read the docs / tech specs. For the second part: Why?